# Setting up files and execute code before tests are run with setupFiles option

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to run some code and have the code executed BEFORE all the tests are run.

My `jest.config.js` configuration:

```
  // truncated...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
      "./jest.setup.ts"
  ]
```

`jest.setup.ts`:

```
async function setUp() {
  const first = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res('this called first');
  })
  const second = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res('this called second');
  })
  first.then((firstRes) => {
    console.log(firstRes)
    second.then(secondRes => console.log(secondRes))
  })
}
beforeAll(done => {
  setUp().then(done => console.log(done));
  done();
})
```

So I ran the tests, and it looks like they aren't being called in order:

```
 PASS  packages/dao/dao.service.spec.ts (5.532 s)
  Dao Tests
    ✓ should be defined (2 ms)
    ✓ get should return null

  console.log
    Running pre-scripts for integration tests...

      at Object.<anonymous> (jest.setup.ts:56:9)

  console.log
    this called first

      at jest.setup.ts:86:13

  console.log
    undefined

      at jest.setup.ts:91:32

  console.log
    this called second

      at jest.setup.ts:87:38

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.612 s, estimated 11 s
Ran all test suites.
```

This output looks like the tests are being run first, and then `jest.setup.ts` is run.

Comment: You should be calling done inside the callback, otherwise it's not waiting for the promise to resolve. Don't call done until the work's... done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions, raw promises with `then` and `done` callback are 3 ways to achieve the same thing in Jest. They shouldn't be mixed together unless necessary.

`setUp` is `async` for nothing, it doesn't chain nested promises. `done` is called synchronously in `beforeAll`, no promises affect the result except that they can cause uncaught errors because they weren't chained.

It should be:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  const first = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res('this called first');
  })

  const second = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res('this called second');
  });

  const firstRes = await first;
  console.log(firstRes);
  const secondRes = await second;
  console.log(secondRes);
})
```